# Is there a way to hide a specific column in a DataGrid when AutoGenerateColumns=True?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF 4.0 DataGrid that is bound to a DataTable using AutoGenerateColumns=True. The columns are dynamic, however I know there is always going to be a column named ID and I would like to hide this column. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

in your datagrid, subscribe for the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event, the event `args` (`DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs`) has the column name and a "`Cancel`", if the column name is ID then set `Cancel = true`.  should do the trick.

Comment: That'd work...although it immediately goes against the MVVM pattern...but will no doubt work.

Comment: Thank you, that will work nicely. I'm not too concerned with MVVM in this case since the DataGrid is part of a custom UserControl and I have no problems using code-behind if it is something that only affects the View.

Comment: @Aaron, if you're relying on the View to generate the MV, then i think you're going to find it's not adherent to MVVM :)

Comment: You can build a view model that exposes both a `DataTable` and a list of columns that auto-generation should skip, have the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event use that list, and tuck yourself into bed at night secure in the knowledge that you've still separated the view from the view model.

Comment: code example http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @javapowered ty for code example. This answer made no sense to me without it.

Answer (score 17):

You can use a behavior (reusable code) to do the job... This way you can use attribute which would centralize the column visibility in one place.

Usage:

```
<Window
...
 xmlns:extension="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary.Extension;assembly=WpfControlLibrary">

<DataGrid ...
    extension:DataGridBehavior.UseBrowsableAttributeOnColumn="True">
```

...

```
public class YourObjectItem
{
    [Browsable(false)]
        public Assembly Assembly { get; set; }
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace HQ.Wpf.Util.Behaviors
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Using this behavior on a dataGRid will ensure to display only columns with "Browsable Attributes"
    /// </summary>
    public static class DataGridBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UseBrowsableAttributeOnColumnProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UseBrowsableAttributeOnColumn",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(DataGridBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, UseBrowsableAttributeOnColumnChanged));

        public static bool GetUseBrowsableAttributeOnColumn(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(UseBrowsableAttributeOnColumnProperty);
        }

        public static void SetUseBrowsableAttributeOnColumn(DependencyObject obj, bool val)
        {
            obj.SetValue(UseBrowsableAttributeOnColumnProperty, val);
        }

        private static void UseBrowsableAttributeOnColumnChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataGrid = obj as DataGrid;
            if (dataGrid != null)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += DataGridOnAutoGeneratingColumn;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn -= DataGridOnAutoGeneratingColumn;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void DataGridOnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            var propDesc = e.PropertyDescriptor as PropertyDescriptor;

            if (propDesc != null)
            {
                foreach (Attribute att in propDesc.Attributes)
                {
                    var browsableAttribute = att as BrowsableAttribute;
                    if (browsableAttribute != null)
                    {
                        if (!browsableAttribute.Browsable)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                        }
                    }

                    // As proposed by "dba" stackoverflow user on webpage: 
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000132/is-there-a-way-to-hide-a-specific-column-in-a-datagrid-when-autogeneratecolumns
                    // I added few next lines:
                    var displayName = att as DisplayNameAttribute;
                    if (displayName != null)
                    {
                        e.Column.Header = displayName.DisplayName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Tested and working on .NET 4.6.1 :)

Comment: Thanks! It is nice to know that it still work fine :) !

Comment: The DataGrid should work this way out of the box IMHO and pick up the header from the DisplayNameAttriibute too!

Comment: Extending @EricOuellet's excellent solution to honor Displayname Property just put           var displayName = att as DisplayNameAttribute;
          if (displayName != null)
          {
            e.Column.Header = displayName.DisplayName;
          } in the loop

Comment: Could someone enlighten me why we have *clr-namespace* set to `WpfControlLibrary.Extension` instead of what is in the code? I.e. for the class in the same project: `xmlns:extension="clr-namespace:HQ.Wpf.Util.Behaviors"`

Answer (score 5):

Other possibility would be `Visibility.Collapsed`:

```
    private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, 
        DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set properties on the columns during auto-generation 
        switch (e.Column.Header.ToString())
        {
            case "rownameYouWantToHide":
                e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's great solution... but... you can have one more abstraction layer
for example let's say you have an object like:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public string Property3 { set; get; }
}
```

You don't want column for Id, so you create new object

```cs
public class Foo2
{
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public string Property3 { set; get; }
}
```

then map/convert Foo to Foo2 and you are done.

Another possible way *(not always possible)* is to change access modifier to **internal**

```cs
public class Foo
{
    internal string Id { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public string Property3 { set; get; }
}
```

this way you won't have Id column generated either.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this using `Browsable` attribute and `Visibility: Collapsed`

Model

```cs
class CourseModel
{
    [Description("")]
    [ReadOnly(false)]
    public bool Select { get; set; } = true; // Checkbox

    [Description("Course ID")]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string ID { get; set; } // Hidden column

    [Description("Course Title")]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Custom control extension:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyProject.FrontEnd.Controls
{
    class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        // Take attributes of POCO, if available (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17255496/979621)

        protected override void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnAutoGeneratingColumn(e);
                var propertyDescriptor = e.PropertyDescriptor as PropertyDescriptor;
                e.Column.Header = propertyDescriptor.Description;
                e.Column.IsReadOnly = propertyDescriptor.IsReadOnly;
                e.Column.Visibility = propertyDescriptor.IsBrowsable 
                                      ? Visibility.Visible 
                                      : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignore; retain field defaults
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```cs
public ObservableCollection<CourseModel> Courses { get; set; }
```

XAML

```
<Window 
    ...
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyProject.FrontEnd.Controls" 
    ...
>
...
<controls:CustomDataGrid x:Name="courses" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Courses, Mode=TwoWay, 
                  NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for 4, however it was not possible in 3.5 SP1, at least without registering for an event which I wanted to avoid at all costs.

What you could do instead is change your generation code to `AutoGenerateColumns=False` then just place the columns you care about within the XAML as the underlying data will all still be placed within the columns appropriately

```
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Display" Binding="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Host" Binding="{Binding HostName}"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Database" Binding="{Binding Database}"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" Binding="{Binding Username}"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Password" Binding="{Binding Password}"/>
```

This will allow you to display the only columns you care about in relation to the underlying model as well as change the `Header` to display as you see fit, so you are not tied to the `Property` name on the model.

Comment: That is not an option for me since I do not know the column names beforehand

Comment: This is not being generated from a model? What does the data look like...?

Comment: The model just contains a DataTable property which contains the data to display in the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently done this and wanted to share my solution:

I just made a view model I wanted the datagrid to follow and for the fields I wanted it to ignore (that is, not auto generate columns for), simply set those fields to private. Worked like a charm and there's no need for unnecessary code.

For example, here's the view model I pass to the view that contains the datagrid. I get all I need by simply setting the fields I don't want as columns to private, shown on the "FullPath" field in my example. I understand this may not be possible in every scenario, but worked for me quite well.

```
namespace dev
{   
    /// <summary>
    /// View model for tag list view in data grid
    /// </summary>
    public class TagDataViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">The JSONPath to this item</param>
        public TagDataViewModel(string path)
        {
            FullPath = path;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets and sets the JSONPath to this item
        /// </summary>
        private string FullPath { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the name
        /// </summary>
        public string Name => ProjectHelpers.GetPropertyValue(FullPath, "Name");

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the address
        /// </summary>
        public string Address => ProjectHelpers.GetPropertyValue(FullPath, "Address");

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the data type
        /// </summary>
        public string DataType => ProjectHelpers.GetPropertyValue(FullPath, "DataType");

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the scan rate
        /// </summary>
        public string ScanRate => ProjectHelpers.GetPropertyValue(FullPath, "ScanRate");

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the scaling type
        /// </summary>
        public string ScalingType => ProjectHelpers.GetPropertyValue(FullPath, "ScalingType");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGridAutoGenColumnEvent" add it to XAML
```

and in the code side paste it and replace your model values to skip:

```
 List<string> HeadersToSkip = new List<string> { "StockStatus" , "ImagePath" , "SupplyID" , "RemarksJson" , "PurchaseRequetID" , "DocumentsFolderPath" ,"" };

            if (HeadersToSkip.Contains( e.Column.Header.ToString()))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
```