# Exclude columns from a databound datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, blend

I have an `ObservableCollection<SolarSystemViewModel>` where `SolarSystemViewModel` derives from the `ViewModelBase`.  The `ViewModelBase` exposes `IsInDesignMode` and `IsInDesignModeStatic` that are showing up in the datagrid when I bind to my `ObservableCollection`.  How can I hide those columns from the datagrid by default without having to generate the XAML with Blend and then disable those columns manually?

Thanks.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Assuming you are using `AutoGenerateColumns=True`, you can't with the default datagrid. You'll need to create the specific columns you want in the view.

Comment: Maybe [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4000132/620360).

Comment: @MetroSmurf I'm not autogenerating the columns, but I realized my question was awfully stupid.  Thanks

Comment: @forTruce - not a stupid question.  There are enough people ready to judge on SO already, don't question yourself. You don't know what you don't know, that's why we have forums like this.  Keep asking and keep learning, and ignore those who forget that they were once beginners.

Answer (score 22):

I've been searching for an answer to this question too.
Here's a pretty nice solution:

Bind the property "OnAutoGeneratingColumn" of your DataGrid like this (attention the XAML is not 100% complete):

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

And in your CodeBehind:

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = (PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor;
    e.Column.Header = propertyDescriptor.DisplayName;
    if (propertyDescriptor.DisplayName == "IsInDesignMode")
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

**"e.Cancel = true;"** will prevent the current column from being generated. That's how you can easily exclude columns from the DataGrid.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite simple once I thought about it. MS left us in good shape because we can access the properties of the ObservableCollection's T value using the Path. This will update the observable collection with results from the datagrid. I use prism for the update/insert side using an ICommand that is binded to a save button. My query using SQLite supports insert and update in the same method which makes life easy. For clarification I'm following MVVM using Unity and Prism.

```
<DataGrid Name="_dgProtocolSource" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-161,-61,-162,-163" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="365" Height="224" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding OCSource, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ColumnName1" Binding="{Binding Path=Property1}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ColumnName2" Binding="{Binding Path=Property2}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ColumnName3" Binding="{Binding Path=Property3}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that this is what the OP wanted. Also your answer barely differs from Chintana Meegamarachchi's.

Answer (score 0):

Please try manually defining the columns.. something along the lines of.

```
<dg:DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = SolarSystemViewModels}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FactionKills}" Header="Faction Kills" />
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Jumps}" Header="Jumps" />
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PodKills}" Header="Pod Kills" />
    <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ShipKills}" Header="Ship Kills" />
  </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

You dont have to use blend for this, just use VS XAML editor

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who found it now after years. Simplest but not always possible way to do this is to make properties you don't want to display in your grid `internal`