# WPF DataGrid force binding DataGridCheckBoxColumn when AutoGenerateColumns for nullable bool

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

We have lots of `DataGrid` with dynamic data binding, so we always use `AutoGenerateColumns=True`. For `bool` columns generates a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` but for a nullable bool (`bool?` in C#) generates the default `DataGridTextColumn`. Is there any way to force the `DataGrid` generate automatically a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` for nullable bool? Prefer not implementation-dependant hacks. Also some code-behind is accepted for example in the `AutoGeneratingColumn`event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should register to AutoGeneratingColumn event and change the generated column based on column type, like so:

```
  private void dataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
        {
             DataGridCheckBoxColumn  checkBoxColumn=new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
            checkBoxColumn.Header = e.Column.Header;
            checkBoxColumn.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName);
            checkBoxColumn.IsThreeState = true;

            // Replace the auto-generated column with the checkBoxColumn.
            e.Column = checkBoxColumn;
           }
    }
```

Comment: Great! I wasn't sure if I can simply replace the generated one with a new `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to try it out - I'm not near VS - but you should be able use this to easily solve it...

> **Look at the other post of mine**...
>   [how to stop a specific column to be generated in DataGrid when the AutoGenerateColumns is set to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830214/how-to-stop-a-specific-column-to-be-generated-in-datagrid-when-the-autogeneratec/15833577#15833577)

Use that 'method' to `bind` to your command
(all is MVVM straight - you just need an `AutoGenerateColumnEvent` attached property.

Then in your command handling, like I did there - replace the column - like already suggested.

1) Use the `Attach` class provided, add namespace etc.

2)
And in your XAML...

```
<DataGrid 
    local:Attach.AutoGenerateColumnEvent="{Binding AutoGeneratingColumnCommand}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

3)
And in your view-model...

```
RelayCommand _autoGeneratingColumnCommand;
public RelayCommand AutoGeneratingColumnCommand 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return _autoGeneratingColumnCommand ?? (_autoGeneratingColumnCommand = new RelayCommand(param => 
        { 
            var e = param as DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs;
            var type = ((PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor).PropertyType;
            if (type == typeof(bool?))
                e.Column = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
        }, 
        param => true)); 
    } 
}
```

**Note: For a more generic solution...**

> **You could use the `PropertyDescriptor`** to get the property type - and
>   make a generic decision based on it - that's pretty much what you need
>   I think, I haven't tried though. So you'd have to try it out.

Comment: Good solution but prefer the other one because we don't use MVVM at all:) and because the solution can be implemented at `DataGrid` level (be have a heavily customized `DataGrid`control and can be implemented there), not the model of the view as should be implemented by default in all `Datagrid`s of the application without having to implement in each view.