# WPF DataGrid Checkbox doesn't update source

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a DataGrid that is using AutoGeneratedColumns. Everything works as expected with the exception of the Checkbox column. When the checkbox is clicked, the data source is not updated. It seems the DataGrid needs to lose focus before the data source is updated. Is there an easy way around this, or do I need to generate the columns manually?

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem x:Name="moNewSystem" Header="_New System" Click="moNewSystem_Click" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="moSaveSystems" Header="_Save Systems" Click="moSaveSystems_Click" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="moLoadSystems" Header="_Load Systems" Click="moLoadSystems_Click" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem x:Name="moExit" Header="E_xit" Click="moExit_Click" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>

    <DataGrid x:Name="dgvSystems" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllSystems, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGeneratingColumn="dgvSystems_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <ListBox x:Name="lstOutput" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    
</Grid>
```

View Model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Systems> allSystems = new ObservableCollection<Systems>();
    public ObservableCollection<Systems> AllSystems 
    { 
        get { return allSystems; }
        set { allSystems = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public class Systems : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        private MainWindow Parent;

        private string symbol;
        public string Symbol
        {
            get { return symbol; }
            set { symbol = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private bool isEnabled;
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return isEnabled; }
            set 
            { 
                isEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                if (isEnabled)
                    StartSystem();
                else StopSystem();
            }
        }

        private void StartSystem()
        {
            Parent.Log("Started");
        }

        private void StopSystem()
        {
            Parent.Log("Stopped");
        }

        public Systems(MainWindow parent)
        {
            Parent = parent;
        }
    }
```

Window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = viewModel;

            foreach (var column in dgvSystems.Columns)
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
        }

        private void moNewSystem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewSystem nsWindow = new NewSystem(this);
            bool? result = nsWindow.ShowDialog();
            switch(result)
            {
                case true:
                    // Add System to collection
                    viewModel.AllSystems.Add(nsWindow.ThisSystem);
                    nsWindow.Close();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void moSaveSystems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void moLoadSystems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void moExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Log(string message)
        {
            string text = string.Format("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, message);
            lstOutput.Items.Insert(0, text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should also share your code-behind, in case you're doing something with MouseLeftButtonUp that is interfering with updating the DataGrid's CheckBox column.

Comment: Edited to include the additional code.

Comment: Am I blind, or is the method 'dgvSystems_MouseLeftButtonUp' missing in codebehind? Does the compiler not moan about is?

Comment: Just a word about convention: your class *Systems* is actually one system. So naming it as plural could be misleading. To avoid conflict with the System Namespace, you may find a better name for your type :-)

Comment: Thanks dba. You are correct about the dgvSystems_MouseLeftButtonUp. I simplified the code before posting and forgot to remove that. I have edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Ah yes, the `switch [...] case true:` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This link might provide the some of the answer for you -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15907332/16052620

The only change, is to set the binding 'UpdateSourceTrigger' property to PropertyChanged.