# Dynamic change of DatagridTextColumn path WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I read a Excel file to a System.Data.Datatable and display it on DataGrid. Everything works fine if columns are created automatically or I know DataGridTextColumns Property path.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ExcelTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reference"  Binding="{Binding Path=ColumnHeader}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Problem is that I do not know what the path will be, because properties are created after opening a file.I would like to create a path e,g, ColumnHeader And change it dynamically during a runtime.

It is easy to dynamically change string value of an textBox with a help of TryGetMember and so on. But with this one I do not know how it would work, since ItemSource is the one that raises TryGetMember, not the column.

Is it possible to do it this way? I know other ways, but when I already have a dataTable...

Comment: use `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`

Comment: Yes, like I wrote, everything works fine if columns are created automatically. I only want to create two columns out of like 50. And I would like to do it with dataTable that I already have.

Comment: it is also doable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830214/how-to-stop-a-specific-column-to-be-generated-in-datagrid-when-the-autogeneratec

Comment: Not related my question

Comment: I a suggested a possible solution outside the box, you can ignore it as you like. btw, nothing stops you from creating DataGridTextColumn after loading datatable

Comment: I know the outside of a box solutions, pretty easy to Google. I asked a specific one and hoping to get a answer to that