# WPF DataGrid - Can I decorate my POCOs with attributes to have custom column names?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, header

I have a DataGrid in WPF and fill it with data like this:

```
public enum Sharing
{
    Equal,
    SurfaceBased,
}

public class Data
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Floor { get; set; }
    public Sharing Sharing { get; set; }
}
    public ObservableCollection<Data> _col = new ObservableCollection<Data>()
                                 {
                                  new Data(){Active = true, Name = "KRL", Floor = 0 },
                                  new Data(){Name = "DAT", Floor = 1},
                                  new Data(){Name = "TRE", Floor = 1},
                                  new Data(){Name = "DUO", Floor = 2},
                                 };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        grid.DataContext = _col;
        grid.ItemsSource = _col;
    }
```

I was wondering if I could use some attributes on the enumerations and the POCO class so that the DataGrid displays them (instead of the variable names) on the headers and ComboCoxes.

Something like this:

```
public enum Sharing
{
    [Name("This is a test")]
    Equal,
    [Name("This is a test 2")]
    SurfaceBased,
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe have a look at something like [Adding data-bindable attributes to C# enums](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169430/Adding-data-bindable-attributes-to-C-enums-using-t)

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work with the codeproject way yet, but I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) that could help (for the column headers at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Here is the way to do it for the Headers:

You add attributes, like `Description` attributes to your Properties.

```
public class MyPOCO
{
    [Description("The amount you must pay")]
    public float Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in a class derived from DataGrid you do this:

```
    protected override void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnAutoGeneratingColumn(e);
            var propDescr = e.PropertyDescriptor as System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor;
            e.Column.Header = propDescr.Description;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.ReportException(ex);
        }
    }
```

For adding custom names to the members of the enumerations, you need to make a custom column. You can see a simple example here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510660/964053.