# WPF DataGrid - Creating a new custom Column

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am trying to create my own checkbox column (replacing the default one), in order to move to more complex data columns later-on, and I have the following code:

```
public class MyCheckBoxColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var cb = new CheckBox();
        var bb = this.Binding as Binding;
        var b = new Binding { Path = bb.Path, Source = cell.DataContext };
        cb.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, b);
        return cb;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var cb = new CheckBox();
        var bb = this.Binding as Binding;
        var b = new Binding { Path = bb.Path, Source = ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty };
        cb.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, b);
        return cb;
    }

    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        var cb = editingElement as CheckBox;
        return cb.IsChecked;
    }

    protected override void CancelCellEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, object uneditedValue)
    {
        var cb = editingElement as CheckBox;
        if (cb != null) cb.IsChecked = (bool)uneditedValue;
    }

    protected override bool CommitCellEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement)
    {
        var cb = editingElement as CheckBox;
        BindingExpression binding = editingElement.GetBindingExpression(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty);
        if (binding != null) binding.UpdateSource();
        return true;// base.CommitCellEdit(editingElement);
    }
}
```

And my custom DataGrid:

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var type = e.PropertyType;
            if (type == typeof(bool))
            {
                var col = new MyCheckBoxColumn();
                col.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) {Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay};
                e.Column = col;
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnAutoGeneratingColumn(e);
            }
            var propDescr = e.PropertyDescriptor as System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor;
            e.Column.Header = propDescr.Description;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.ReportException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, everything seems nice except for two things:

- It seems that the only used method in in `MyCheckBoxColumn` is the `GenerateElement()`. All the other methods are not used. I have put breakpoints in them and they never get hit...
- I use an `ObservableCollection` as a data source and, while the rest of the columns notify me when they get changed, this one doesn't.

The odd thing is that the `bool` value gets changed when you check/uncheck the checkbox, but without notification and without passing through `CommitCellEdit()`.
Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

**EDIT :**

It seems that if I return a `TextBlock` from inside `GenerateElement()` it makes the other methods to be called (the notification problem doesn't get fixed though). But why doesn't this work with with CheckBoxes? How does the default check box column work???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. Here is the complete code for a custom CheckBox column. It seems that, in order to have a control like a checkbox as a display (not editing) element in a DataGrid you have to make it hit-test-invisible. Or you can simply use a TextBlock to display some character that resembles a checkmark:

```
public class MyCheckBoxColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var cb = new CheckBox() { IsHitTestVisible = false, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center };
        var bb = this.Binding as Binding;
        var b = new Binding { Path = bb.Path, Source = dataItem, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        cb.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, b);
        return cb;
//          var cb = new TextBlock() { TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center };
//          var bb = this.Binding as Binding;
//          var b = new Binding { Path = bb.Path, Source = dataItem, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Converter = new MyBoolToMarkConverter() };
//          cb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
//          return cb;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var cb = new CheckBox() { HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center };
        var bb = this.Binding as Binding;
        var b = new Binding { Path = bb.Path, Source = dataItem, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        cb.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, b);
        return cb;
    }

    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        var cb = editingElement as CheckBox;
        if (cb != null) return cb.IsChecked;
        return false;
    }

    protected override void CancelCellEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, object uneditedValue)
    {
        var cb = editingElement as CheckBox;
        if (cb != null) cb.IsChecked = (bool)uneditedValue;
    }

    protected override bool CommitCellEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement)
    {
        // The following 2 lines seem to help when sometimes the commit doesn't happen (for unknown to me reasons).
        //var cb = editingElement as CheckBox;
        //cb.IsChecked = cb.IsChecked;
        BindingExpression binding = editingElement.GetBindingExpression(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty);
        if (binding != null) binding.UpdateSource();
        return true;// base.CommitCellEdit(editingElement);
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class MyBoolToMarkConverter : IValueConverter
{
    const string cTick = "■";

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(bool)) return "";
        bool val = (bool)value;
        return val ? cTick : "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(string)) return false;
        string val = (string)value;
        return val == cTick;
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't know why no-one answers my questions. Is it because WPF is supposed to be abandoned by M$ and you don't care about it anymore? Is it that you don't know the answer? Anyway, WinForms, and many more were supposed to be abandoned technologies and they are still in use today. M$ just wants to push developers to promote their cell-phone toys.

Comment: I wouldn't say WPF is abandoned, but I expect many people don't dig this deep into control authoring.

Comment: NoOne did answer your question :D