# Do not map ReactiveUI properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reactiveui

Using the Entity Framework Code First, I've created some objects to store data in my database. I implement the ReactiveObject class from the ReactiveUI library in these objects, so I get notifications whenever a prorerty changes for a more responsive UI.

But implementing this adds 3 properties, namely Changed, Changing and ThrowExceptions to my objects. I don't really think this is a problem, but when loading the tables in a DataGrid, these all get a column too.

Is there a way to hide these properties? I cannot just manually define the columns because I have 1 datagrid for all my tables, which I select from a combobox..

Solution found below and also here: [Is there a way to hide a specific column in a DataGrid when AutoGenerateColumns=True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000132/is-there-a-way-to-hide-a-specific-column-in-a-datagrid-when-autogeneratecolumns)

```
    void dataTable_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> removeColumns = new List<string>()
        {
            "Changing",
            "Changed",
            "ThrownExceptions"
        };

        if (removeColumns.Contains(e.Column.Header.ToString()))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a few ways to do this with Code First. First option is to annotate the property with the [`NotMappedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx):

```
[NotMapped]
public bool Changed { get; set; }
```

Now, this is for your information. Because you are inheriting a base class and do not have access to that class' properties, you cannot use this. Second option is to use [Fluent Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx) with the [`Ignore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.6) method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Ignore(e => e.Changed);
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Ignore(e => e.Changing);
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Ignore(e => e.ThrowExceptions);
```

To access the `DbModelBuilder`, override the [`OnModelCreating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method in your `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // .. Your model configuration here
}
```

Another option is to create a class inheriting [`EntityTypeConfiguration<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
public abstract class ReactiveObjectConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : ReactiveObject
{

    protected ReactiveObjectConfiguration()
    {
        Ignore(e => e.Changed);
        Ignore(e => e.Changing);
        Ignore(e => e.ThrowExceptions);
    }
}

public class YourEntityConfiguration : ReactiveObjectConfiguration<YourEntity>
{
    public YourEntityConfiguration()
    {
        // Your extra configurations
    }
}
```

Advantages of this method is that you define a baseline configuration for all of your `ReactiveObject` and get rid of all the definitions redundancies.

More information on Fluent Configuration in the links above.

Comment: I've tried adding the Ignore's in the OnModelCreating, but the columns are still displayed in my datagrid. I think this is because the DataGrid doesn't know these properties are ignored in entity framework

Comment: After some digging, I found this question that solved my remaining issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000132/is-there-a-way-to-hide-a-specific-column-in-a-datagrid-when-autogeneratecolumns Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @TomVandenbussche Glad you could find a related answer! I was about to write up regarding the DataGrid configuration. ;)