# WPF DataGrid Remove Column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have created a DataGrid in WPF from a DataTable with `AutoGenerateColumns = true`. In the VM I have a command property for adding and deleting columns which manipulates the underlying DataTable.

When I call `AddColumn` from the main XAML window via `Command="{Binding AddColumn}"` it works as expected but when I call the RemoveColumn from a resource file with a context menu it calls the command property (im able to step through the code) but does not update the Grid.

```
<MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppViewModel}, Path=DeleteColumn}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

I now updated both commands to only set the DataTable to null, ie `Dt = null` and for the AddColumn this works as expected and removed the Grid and columns but for the RemoveColumn it does nothing... I also see no errors in the output window in regard to binding and when stepping through the code the property is called. I also tried to set the column to invisible which also did not work.

**UPDATE**

I call the DeleteColumn from the following (simplified) code in a resources file.

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, ConverterParameter=*, Converter={StaticResource AfterDashConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}" Value="Green">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppViewModel}, Path=DeleteColumn}" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Grid.ContextMenu>
                            <DataGridColumnHeader x:Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The commands are very simple, the AddColumn works as its directly in my main view and the DeleteColumn does not as its in the above resource file. I have checked the commands fire properly.

```
    AddColumn = new RelayCommand(_ =>
    {
        Dt = null;
    }, true);

    DeleteColumn = new RelayCommand(column =>
    {
        Dt = null;
    }, true);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to hide a specific column in a DataGrid when AutoGenerateColumns=True?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000132/is-there-a-way-to-hide-a-specific-column-in-a-datagrid-when-autogeneratecolumns)

Comment: the above is at load time, I need this from a button command on an ad hoc basis

Comment: @InContext That's weird trying the same flow and getting different results. Can you post some more code? Maybe the AddCommand from XAML or their implementations?

Comment: im a step closer, it seems that in my resource the code actually creates a new instance of the AppViewModel instead of reusing the existing one... can you advise how I can bind a resource style as above to the view model it is used in without recreating said viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

the main issue was my resource was creating a new viewmodel so it was not calling / impacting the VM instance that my view was dependent on. To fix this I needed to set the `DataContext` of my `ContextMenu` parent control (which was a grid) as follows:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyType}}}
```

If you just call the following it *will* create a new instance of your ViewModel and use that:

```
<MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppViewModel}, Path=DeleteColumn}" />
```