# WPF XAML Template from code fails if it contains eventhandler

Tags: wpf, event-handling, datatemplate, xamlparseexception

I am loading datatemplates to my TabControl dynamicly at runtime. For each tab im displaying the proper datagrid for that type using ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DetailsDataGridTemplateSelector}"
I need to register KeyDown on the datagrid within the template. This works if used in xaml of cource. But when trying to parse xaml in run-time it fails for:

**KeyDown=""DataGrid_KeyDown""**

```
    public DataTemplate CreateTemplate(IEnumerable<string> model)
    {
       
        string xamlTemplate = $@"<DataTemplate>                    
        <DataGrid ItemsSource=""{{Binding Items}}"" AutoGenerateColumns=""False"" 
                  SelectionMode=""Extended"" SelectionUnit=""Cell"" KeyDown=""DataGrid_KeyDown"">
        <DataGrid.Columns> ";
        foreach (var prop in model)
        {
            xamlTemplate += $@"<DataGridTextColumn Header=""{prop}"" Binding=""{{Binding {prop}, 
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}}""/>";
        }
        xamlTemplate += @"</DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>";

        var context = new ParserContext();
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
        
        var template = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(xamlTemplate, context);
        return template;
    }
```

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Failed to create a 'KeyDown' from the text 'DataGrid_KeyDown'.' Line number '2' and line position '127'.'
ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

How can I attach a keydown event handler for the control inside the template when parsing at runtime?

Comment: What a pain to see such code. What is wrong with XAML? Obviously the signature of your event handler is wrong. Either wrong number of parameters or wrong type of parameters.

Comment: You do understand that im using this more than once for this specific tabcontrol? You would rather have thousands of lines with boilerplate xaml in your code base, fine. But that is not what im asking.

Comment: You  always should define the template in XAML, where you get Intellisense and IDE support. If you put it into a resource dictionary it can be reused unlimited times. What thousands of lines boilerplate code are you talking about? The basic template would look like the clumsy string in your code, except: Intellisense support (e.g. suggestions), Syntax checker, IDE XAML  refactoring tools, without the overhead of dealing with collections as this is implicitly handled through the markup, designer support (preview, property manager) and more.

Comment: Using the IDE code generator, would have generated you an event handler with the proper signature and you wouldn't have to come here to ask for help. There is absolutely no good reason to write XAML code as plain strings and write all the boiler plate (e.g., dealing with the parser) for what is done in XAML implicitly. You make yourself suffer. This question is the proof.

Comment: You should learn about implicit `DataTemplate`. Then create a data model for each tab variation..Define a template for each model type. Get rid of the template selector and done.

Comment: This link [Microsoft Docs: Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0) is currently down. But it should be online soon. I recommend the read.

Comment: Im not recommending this or anything like that. Doing something down these lines made sense for that certain control. Basicly I had a problem, then found a solution to that. Now I have two problem. :) I might revise this and create the templates after all.

Comment: I see. To be honest, I doubt that _"Doing something down these lines made sense for that certain control"_. I wrote a lot of complex controls, but I never had to write such code. I never saw a colleague writing such code. Only here on Stackoverflow  from time to time I see some  brave coders doing it.  Chances are high that you are missing something and are intrigued by what you think is a good solution, but solves a problem totally the wrong way. Generally this will introduce more problems sooner or later. I was not mentioning this in order to mock you. Have you fixed your problem now?

Comment: After different routes and efforts I ended up using the annotation system on the model-types, it allready has attribute for serializable, and orderNo. Its not perfect because the model is directly tied to the user interface. But it doesnt matter in this use-case because every property on the model which is serializable must be visible in the datagrid. :) I used the behavior from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34145112/5283978